# Cannot find control with path, FormArray Angular

Tags: angular, path, angular-forms

I'm new to the Angular framework and need some help.

I am building an Angular form with Material where I can add new users to a table by a stepper (through the service).
And I have and error:

> Error: Cannot find control with path: 'usersArray -> 0 -> name'.

Also please indicate the errors in the code if they are.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

[Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jnnlnc)

Comment: Not actual,
I don't use formControlName in formArray.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
          formArray: this.formBuilder.array([
            this.formBuilder.group({
              name: ['', Validators.required],
            }),
            this.formBuilder.group({
              dob: ['', Validators.required],
            }),
            this.formBuilder.group({
              sex: ['', Validators.required],
            }),
            this.formBuilder.group({
              snils: ['', Validators.required],
            }),
          ])
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<div [formGroupName]="i" >

  .....
</div>
```